# Store warning to a file MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

I was trying to load some data from a .csv file to a table. I used the Load statement with the IGNORE so that I could load the data. After loading the data it showed that I have  12385 warnings. When I do SHOW WARNINGS; it only show me 64 lines of notes and warnings. Is there a way I can store all the warnings to a file, like a text file or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`max_error_count`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_error_count) system variable to the number of errors and warnings that it should save. The maximum allowed size of this setting is `65535`.